# Can not install Ubuntu on Samsung Ultrabook Series 5 (Win 7!)

Tags: installation, dual-boot, samsung, ultrabook

I have a Samsung Ultrabook Series 5 with Windows 7 (which I want to keep)...

I can boot from a USB stick without a problem and ubuntu work fine, but when I want to install it, the installation progress is stopped and it won't go further. It stop with the message: Checking filesystem

Before that, I got also a message, that the system can't unmount the /cdrom (which the ultrabook doesn't have!)

Thank you very much for help!

Comment: What method do you use to install? Do you go into LiveUSB and clicks "install Now" or do you install it from Wubi ?

Comment: Hello! Thx for the fast reply! I use the LiveUSB and there I choose "install now"

Comment: Ok. when its "clicked", how far can you get? Did you get past the "install alongside windows / Partition preferences" ? If so, what did you choose?

Comment: Hello! I can choose how I want to install it (Windows 7 and Ubuntu together), the time zone and at last the name and password... between these steps the "/cdrom unmount failure" comes up, but with "next" it doesn't show up again... not the commercials from Ubuntu showing up and on the bottom it says "checking filesystem"...

Comment: It looks like its incompatible with your computer. I am sorry, i am not know to such issues, and you might have to wait for someone else to reply to you :) Good luck!

Comment: Sad, but thx :-(

Comment: Does you unit have an SSD? Can you choose Try Ubuntu instead, and see what happens?

Comment: @Torsten: it is very unlikely Ubuntu can not be installed when the live session runs fine on your hardware. How arew your partitions set up?

Comment: Hello! Yes, the ultrabook have a SSD (128 GB)... when I choose try Ubuntu it just work... but I can not install it... at the moment I just have the normal Windows partitions...

Comment: So... I tried now different steps, e.g. also umount the /cdrom... But now I get the following error: "Partitions 1 on /dev/sdb have been written, but we have been unable to inform the kernel of the change, probably because it/they are in use. As a result, the old partition(s) will remain in use. You should reboot now before making further changes. .... I really do not know, what to do next!?!?

Comment: I found a hint: http://schoolsplay.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/install-ubuntu-linux-on-a-samsung-series-5-ultrabook-with-ssd/ ... but.. i do not want to wipe my Win7...

Comment: Nope... I cant fix it... it runs perfectly via an USB stick, but the installations still stops... :-(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems theres some strangeness going on.  The way I managed it eventually was.. to *wipe* windows. Then install Ubuntu .. from external flash disk, (not from an external hard drive)

You need to umount the cdrom before attempting install once in live. Then partition your drive and make sure grub is set to the right device, then install.

If you have configured all the right hard drive partitions, it should install ok.  Then.. once you try to login, it may give you the 'GRUB' error.. which only lists the memtest..

I think this may have happened because I tried mulitiple installs, there are two ways to fix this .. one .. which I did not bother with because of slow internet in my country.. was to download a grub fix iso for ubuntu.. the second was to .. 'repair' the installation.. with a fresh ubuntu install.. which took a while ...

Then  it booted into the glorious Ubuntu logon screen (startup takes like 5 seconds or less) very beautiful slick unity interface which I have gotten used to.  The only prob is that it munches battery fast.. and not all the battery features are there. (some battery issues).

Also, alsa works better with progs like skype for sound (otherwise scratchy) need to configure SSD. In your case you may be able to do a side by side with windows.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a 530U3C? The answer or "workaround" for this model provided in several forums and websites is to install Ubuntu with Compatibility Support Module (CSM). You "just" have to disable fast boot and secure boot and make sure to boot from CSM (or legacy) only.

And you have to blacklist the samsung-laptop hardware driver [1]. The problem is that it is not possible to boot both OS. If you want to run Ubuntu in CSM you have to format your HDD. So actually there is no choice.

Nevertheless, it is safer to not install any other OS on the above mentioned machine until the bug is officially fixed by Samsung.

[1] This info is by Greg Kroah-Hartman. See his post on G+: https://plus.google.com/111049168280159033135/posts/h7FjkQKZHKT